# How to determine the type of a variable from the type of another variable

Tags: typescript

Suppose, I have a tab with variable named `tabValue`
At this time, there are only two options for the tab, one is video and one is article.
But I need to request different interfaces when the tab is switched, the type of the variable named result should be `videoResult` and `articleResult`, how do I make the type of result inferred from the type of tabValue.

```
let result: videoResult[] | articleResult[] = []

// the type of the result should be videoResult[]
let tabValue: 'video' | 'article' = 'video'

// tabValue will change,the type of the result should be articleResult[]
tabValue = 'article'
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a single object with discriminated unions (otherwise, I don't think this behavior is possible):

```
interface VideoResult { length: number }

interface ArticleResult { paragraphs: number }

type State = {
    result: VideoResult[];
    tabValue: "video";
} | {
    result: ArticleResult[];
    tabValue: "article";
};

const state: State = {
    result: [{ length: 42 }],
    tabValue: "video",
};

if (state.tabValue === "video") {
    state.result
    //    ^? VideoResult[]
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3pjm)

Comment: This is a good idea, thank you for your answer